# Specialization of nested template class inside template class after its declaration

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have definition of my own bool type

```
template<bool b>
struct Bool {
    constexpr static bool value = b;
};

using True = Bool<true>;
using False = Bool<false>;
```

I am trying to get something like haskell Bool instance of class Eq.

```
template<typename T>
struct Eq {
    template<typename R>
    struct equal;

    template<typename R>
    struct notEqual {
        using value = typename not_<typename equal<T, R>::value>::value;
    };
};
```

I wonder, how to do a specialization of class "equal". To be more clear, I want something like this:

```
template<bool a>
template<bool b>
struct Eq<Bool<a>>::equal<Bool<b>> {
    using value = typename std::conditional<a == b, True, False>::type;
};
```

Is there a solution to do this? I tried to do this trick:

```
template<bool a>
struct Eq<Bool<a>>::equal<Bool<a>> {
    using value = True;
};
```

but the compiler tells me "'`mtp::Eq<T>::equal`': too many template arguments". Thank you for your help.

Comment: Notice that `std::true_type`, `std::false_type` (based on [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)) exist

Comment: and [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) also.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specialize on a dependent template like `Bool<a>`. The following will work:

```
template<typename T>
template<bool b>
struct Eq<T>::equal<Bool<b>> {
    using value = /* ... */;
};
```

You can use `std::enable_if_t` to ensure that `T` is a `Bool`, and use another template to extract the value of that `Bool` type.

[**live example on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x39ceE)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to partial specialize `Eq<Bool<a>>::equal<Bool<b>>`, you have to do it in several parts:

```
template <bool b>
struct Eq<Bool<b>> {
    template<typename R>
    struct equal;

    template<typename R>
    struct notEqual {
        using value = typename not_<typename equal<T, R>::value>::value;
    };
};
```

then

```
template<bool a>
template<bool b>
struct Eq<Bool<a>>::equal<Bool<b>> {
    using value = typename std::conditional<a == b, True, False>::type;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74429df375cd6329)

Comment: The problem is that struct "notEqual" is the same for all of the instances, either it is bool or anything else. I would like to avoid writing its definition for every type.

Comment: Why not have `template <typename LHS, typename LHS> struct equal;` that you can partial specialize as you want, then `struct Eq::equal` only forward to this `struct`.

Comment: `template<typename T> struct Eq { template <R> using equal = std::is_same<T, R>; };` would be enough IMO, (or `std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, R>, True, False>;` to use your type as result). No specializations needed.

Comment: It is great solution for bool type, I suppose. But what if I want to compare two strings by calculating hash. The rule of comparing can be anything, so I don't think that `std::is_same` is gonna fit here

Comment: As I said, a (non inner) `template <typename LHS, typename LHS> struct equal` seems more appropriate to your need. (then you might wrap it in `struct Eq` if you rally want it).